# Animejs animate text on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, anime.js

I want to use animejs to get some text animation in my website but I need little help. I want that text to be animated when I scroll to a specific section or area.

This is the snippet I want to change:

- http://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#14

Comment: Your requirements are too vague. Please be more specific with what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry I am new in forum next time i will remember :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)? It is a jQuery compatible library that allows you to trigger a function upon scrolling to it.

Comment: Aaahaa.. Thanks this is what I was looking for :D

Comment: Great, glad I could help!